# how to use left outer join after left join for this tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have 4 tables that I want to join in order to get the necessary data in them.

**Table A.**

```
id | name | deleted | amount | due_date   | status
1  | a    | 0       | 10     | 2016-07-18 | Unpaid
2  | b    | 0       | 20     | 2016-07-19 | Unpaid
3  | c    | 0       | 15     | 2016-07-18 | Unpaid
```

**Table B**

```
id | name   | due_date   | status
1  | a      |            | Unpaid
2  | b      |            | Unpaid
3  | c      |            | Unpaid
4  | d      | 2016-07-19 | Unpaid
```

**Table C**

```
id | table_d_id | table_a_id
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 2          | 2
3  | 3          | 3
```

**Table D**

```
id | 
1
2
3
```

What I want to do here is to retrieve the data at Table B with due_date and an unpaid status, and that it is not found in Table A.

My current query:

```
SELECT  A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*  
FROM A  
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.name= A.name 
INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.id  
INNER JOIN D ON C.id = D.id  
WHERE A.deleted=0 AND ((B.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND B.status = "Unpaid") OR (A.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND A.status = "Unpaid")) 
GROUP BY D.id
```

What this query currently does is that it only gets the data in the tables except for id 4 at table B, Which I was hoping to retrieve also since it has an unpaid status.

Comment: First thing LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN both are same

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar I did not know that I just checked google and saw that OUTER joins get everything from both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use left join  (and in you sample the b.column is name  not number ..)

```
SELECT  A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*  
FROM B  
LEFT JOIN A_cstm ON A.id = A_cstm.id_c  
LEFT  JOIN A ON B.name = A.name 
INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.id  
INNER JOIN D ON C.id = D.id  
WHERE A.deleted=0 AND ((B.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND B.status = "Unpaid") OR (A.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND A.status = "Unpaid")) 
GROUP BY D.id
```

The  table   A_cstm  is not described in you model  (i have removed  for clarity ..)
 and i have change the order of th join  using FROM B and left join A instead of your FROM A .. left join B

```
SELECT  A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*  
FROM B  
LEFT  JOIN A ON B.name = A.name 
INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.id  
INNER JOIN D ON C.id = D.id  
WHERE A.deleted=0 AND ((B.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND B.status = "Unpaid") OR (A.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND A.status = "Unpaid")) 
GROUP BY D.id
```

Comment: Edited to fix the mistake, but after trying the query it still doesn't get the 4th element at table B

Comment: I have update the anser .. with some suggestions   ..   hope useful

Comment: Is there no other way of doing this without changing the FROM since, I cannot change that part, I can only add join statements.

Comment: Seems weird that you can't change the from ..i think you don't obtain the 4th element just because you start form the table A (with 3 element)

Comment: I am using sugarcrm and it only allows customization to a certain degree and that is why I am limited in interfering with the main query and can only add some queries after its default query. So that seems the case why I can't retrieve the 4th element, I have found a possible solution and will post a different question for it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query

```
SELECT  A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*  
FROM A  
LEFT JOIN A_cstm ON A.id = A_cstm.id_c  
LEFT JOIN B ON B.number = A.name 
INNER JOIN C ON A_cstm.id_c = C.id
INNER JOIN D ON C.table_d_id = D.id  
WHERE A.deleted=0 AND ((B.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND B.status = "Unpaid") OR (A.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND A.status = "Unpaid")) 
GROUP BY D.id
```

Comment: It still won't get the 4th element of Table B

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*  
FROM B  
LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON A.name= B.name 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.id = B.id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN D ON D.id = B.id  
WHERE A.deleted=0 AND ((B.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND B.status = "Unpaid") OR (A.due_date < "2016-07-20" AND A.status = "Unpaid")) 
GROUP BY D.id
```

Comment: I cannot change the FROM A to FROM B. So I need a solution using FROM A