# combine two tables without any similar values (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, join, merge

I found this query that can combine two tables with different number of rows and without any related fields:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table1 a, table2 b;
```

Now my problem is that in my case I cannot change the value of the FROM.

> Example I have this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

> I cannot change that to:

```
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

At most, I can only add statements after **FROM table_name LEFT JOIN somedefaulttable ON somedefaulttable2.id = somedefaulttable .id_c**. (I forgot to add this important detail, I can only add custom queries after this line, I cannot remove this predetermined LEFT JOIN as this is system generated) The reason for this is because I am restricted by the CRM I am using, and I cannot edit the default select value but I can add additional custom queries after the said statement.

Now what my main problem here is that I need to combine a different table in my Query and I cannot use join as they don't have any common values and their number of rows are also different, I also tried using JOIN before to no avail, and thus decided to try using a different approach such as merging the two tables.

This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473884/how-to-use-left-outer-join-after-left-join-for-this-tables/38473960) to my previous question where I was using JOIN to achieve my goal of combining the tables. In this link, you can see that I want to combine Table A and Table 4 but I cannot do so with JOIN as they have a different number of rows and that I am limited in changing my current Query to fit the posted answer.

**Table A.**

```
id | name | deleted | amount | due_date   | status
1  | a    | 0       | 10     | 2016-07-18 | Unpaid
2  | b    | 0       | 20     | 2016-07-19 | Unpaid
3  | c    | 0       | 15     | 2016-07-18 | Unpaid
```

**Table B**

```
id | name   | due_date   | status
1  | a      |            | Unpaid
2  | b      |            | Unpaid
3  | c      |            | Unpaid
4  | d      | 2016-07-19 | Unpaid
```

**Table C**

```
id | table_d_id | table_a_id
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 2          | 2
3  | 3          | 3
```

**Table D**

```
id | 
1
2
3
```

Comment: @Jens sorry about that, remove the tag. It is MySQL

Comment: hey why don't you try join?

Comment: @vishal I already did as stated in my previous question, but the problem is that my main table has lesser rows than the table I want to join, and also, I want to retrieve everything at table 4 with some conditions

Comment: can you update your questions with the tables

Comment: @vishal updated with table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for (inner) joining two tables without a JOIN Statement.

```
SELECT a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y FROM  table1 a, table2 b WHERE a.x = b.x
```

What I do not understand is, how different numbers of rows affect the requested solution.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a link of one to many between the tables
with your example and number of rows you inserted you should try this:

```
     SELECT TableC.*
     FROM TableB, TableD INNER JOIN (TableA INNER JOIN TableC ON TableA.ID =       TableC.table_a_id) ON TableD.ID = TableC.table_d_id;
```

this will bring all the records of table C